# Algorithm to check track of shortest path

Tags: algorithm, matlab, shortest-path

I have a matrix `A` of size `IxJ` with each element (weight) defining the distance between nodes `i` and `j`. I want to check the shortest path between each pair of nodes and have used the `Brain Connectivity Toolbox` script `charpath.m` for this previously. However, this algorithm does not tell me exactly which path is taken, only the length.

Now my question is:
Is anyone familiar with a Matlab algorithm that provides the path taken between each node pair? E.g. if a shortest path between node `1` and `2` is `4`, it should output the path taken (e.g. `[1,74,43,4]`). Ideally in case of multiple shortest path of the same length it should report all of these paths.

Comment: Your might look into [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). There are several implementations on matlab central(e.g. [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36140-dijkstra-algorithm))

Comment: If you have bioinformatics toolbox there's `shortestpath`, `graphshortestpath`, `allshortestpaths`, etc.

Comment: I don't have the toolbox unfortunately, but the Dijkstra implementation on matlab central looks usefull, thanks @hitzg!

Comment: You may consider [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), especially if the edge weights can be negative. MATLAB implementation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922-matlabbgl/content/matlab_bgl/johnson_all_sp.m).

Comment: That one doesn't seem to report shortest path tracks, only length of a given shortest path, or am I wrong?